# How to downgrade from Firebase auth with Identity Platform to Legacy Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I may have upgraded Firebase auth to Firebase auth with Identity Platform GCP. I came to know it has a Paid Tier and I really don't use any upgraded options other than basic auth.

I want to go back (downgrade) to [Firebase Legacy Auth](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/product-comparison)

Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth?authuser=0&hl=en#identity-platform) don't mention how to downgrade. Nor anything is mentioned in Google Cloud Platform [docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to).

Answer (score 3):

*firebaser here*

At the final step in the upgrade process, you get this dialog:

[image]

As you can see at the bottom there: <kbd>You won't be able to reverse this decision</kbd>, so there is indeed no way to reverse the upgrade.

In some cases our support team may be able to do something, so [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) if you think your case warrants that check.